# Run Go repository locally from Windows

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I searched and followed many articles and documentations. So far no good. I've installed Go for windows from [here](https://golang.org/doc/install).
***go version go1.16.3 windows/amd64***.
And now I want to run cloned Go project(named 'go-scrapers') locally. I've set system variable path to my downloaded git repository folder

[image]

inside *go-scrapers* folder I created 3 new folders(**pkg,src,bin**)
How do I run the project?

here's the **go env**

```
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\Devin\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\Devin\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\Devin\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\Devin\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.16.3
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=NUL
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\Devin\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build488719353=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Comment: indeed, according to the official documentation this is not the right way to configure the system get go running smoothly, as we all do. Have you read the doc ?

Comment: looks like you should not update environment variables when using the MSI auto installer prepared for you. You might want to unset your configuration, uninstall / reinstall or try the fix option if any. Then beforre toying around with options you dont understand yet well, share the output of `go env` here.

Comment: dont forget to restart vscode and any prompts opened.

Comment: your goenv looks fine, I don't think you need to re-install anything. but make sure to check out some more tutorials how to work with go, especially go modules.

Comment: @mh-cbon ok I've updated the question with env now. Where should I get started?

Comment: seems right. I guess you can create a folder, run go mod init, go get xxxx or git clone a repository then run go get ./... to fetch its dependecies and go for it.

Comment: you should continue there https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/getting-started#code

Comment: @mh-cbon go built and 'go mod tidy' worked fine as in the doc. but when run 'go run .'  I got this error .  main.go:7:2: package goscraper/config is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\goscraper\config)
main.go:8:2: package goscraper/router is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\goscraper\router)
main.go:9:2: package goscraper/threads is not in GOROOT (C:\Program Files\Go\src\goscraper\threads)   Should I open another case for this error?

Comment: you have to checkout this repo in the appropirate folder so the runtime can locate it to build the executable. But because it is not `provider.com/user/project` format, we dnt know where that is from.

Comment: maybe this is some old code from go1.15 ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with Visual Studio Code, but I can give you a more general answer. First you can write up your library, this usually goes at the top level of the repo, as if you put it deeper (like `pkg` or `src`) then it makes the `import` path longer. Example package file:

```
package multiply

func TimesTwo(n int) int {
   return n * 2
}
```

then you can create a program that uses the library. If you just have one program you can use a structure like this:

```
multiply.go
multiplier/
   main.go
```

or if you have multiple programs, you can do this:

```
multiply.go
mult-one/
   main.go
mult-two/
   main.go
```

Or:

```
multiply.go
   bin/
      mult-one/
         main.go
      mult-two/
         main.go
```

Instead of `bin`, you usually see `cmd`, but up to you. Also, you don't need to mess with `GOPATH` like you did. Here is an example program file:

```
package main
import "multiply"

func main() {
   n := multiply.TimesTwo(9)
   println(n == 18)
}
```

To create the module, go back to the top of the repo, and run:

```
go mod init multiply
```

Note that if you are going to share the project, you want to use something like `example.com/user/multiply` instead. Finally, to run the program, go to the program folder and run `go build`, or if it's just one file, you can do `go run main.go`.

https://golang.org/cmd/go